# What does "No valid rules have been specified for JavaScript files" mean?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint, tsconfig

I have a React - Typescript created with:

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

It compiles fine, but every time I see this message or warning:

```
No valid rules have been specified for JavaScript files
```

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

```
> react-scripts-ts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.8.3 and /Users/julian/my-app/tsconfig.json
No valid rules have been specified for JavaScript files
Compiled successfully.
```

My tscongif.json and tslint.json files can be found here: https://gist.github.com/JulianG/be82d9fa20f48f60ce10371fa5095230

Comment: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3735#issuecomment-383115457

Comment: Thank you! That issue contains the answer. I'll answer my own question to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3735#issuecomment-383115457 I found the following:

Because my `tsconfig.json` contained `"allowJs": true`, a `jsRules` key was needed in my `tslint.json`.

The solution was to simply add a rule to `tslint.json` like this:

```
    "jsRules": {
      "no-empty": true
    }
```

Thanks to @explosion-pills for point to the answer.

Comment: @Evan and JulianG, I am getting this "ERROR: No valid rules have been specified" for Type Script during my Run Code Analysis task in TFS 2017 Build definition and I don't have "allowJs": true in my tsconfig.json, so in this case should i still add jsRules key in my tslint.json?

Comment: @SRP Can you share your `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json`?

Comment: I have shared the files at this link, can you please have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156695/why-does-tfs-2017-sonar-build-definition-gives-no-valid-rules-have-been-specifie

Comment: request you to have a look at tsconfig.json and tslint.json files shared at the above link.

Comment: hi! I'm sorry I forgot to check your files before. I've never seen the "no valid rules" error for Typescript. Have you tried to isolate the problem? for instance re-creating it in a new repository that you can share?